# Not all stylesheet show up in developer tools (Firefox)

Tags: css, firefox, web, responsiveness

Suddenly (today) not all stylesheet of my website http://k-dushi.com/index.php show up in developer tools (Firefox). It looks like it keeps trying to load stylesheets (loading icon keeps spinning). Also it seems that some styles to make the website responsive are not loaded properly. Does anyone have a clue how to fix this? I have been trying so many things and am really out of ideas.

Thank you!

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: It says nothing specific. Some stylesheets are just not showing up and the loading icon keeps rotating..

Comment: I created new stylesheets. Website looks good and responsive again but I still don't see all stylesheets in Firefox developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

Close the developer tools and then re-open the stylesheet editor (shift + f7). Does the job for me.
Also the problem occurs only with a live internet connection, although all the stylesheets are loaded properly. So, go offline and its all fine again.